UK visa type query
Do I need to apply for a standard tourist visa or business visa if the company is sponsoring my trip for exploring business opportunities in UK?
It says on UKVI that tourist visa can be used to attend meetings and conferences too.

The UK doesn’t have a business visitor visa. Provided what you intend to do during the trip is listed in Permitted Activities, the Standard Visitor visa is appropriate.

So do i need a business visa or tourist?

@Mohd, there is no business nor a tourist visa, you apply for a standard visa, as Traveller wrote in the answer.
